# Assign Public static $variable from another function (Different modal file)

Tags: php

I have this variable as below in my class file.

```
public static $Whitelist = array(
        '10.10.10.1',
        '10.10.10.2',
        '10.10.10.5',
);
```

I'm trying to convert it so that I can have the list from my database instead of hard coding like below:

```
public static $Whitelist = IPWhitelist::getIPWhitelist();
```

However, it return an error saying that the syntax is wrong. How do i fix it? How come I can assign an array to it but not a function that also returns an array? Thanks.

---

**EDIT**:
It actually contains 3 files here.. let me explain more.

File 1: (config modal file)

```
class Config{
    public static $Whitelist = IPWhitelist::getIPWhitelist();
}
```

File 2: (database modal file)

```
class IPWhitelist{
    public function getIPWhitelist($type = 1){
           //some database code here

            return $array_total_ips;
        }
}
```

File 3: (main file)

```
$ip_list = Config::$Whitelist;
```

Comment: I would convert this to a static function. The function itself can make sure that the list is only fetched once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Static properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties) obey the same rules as [`const`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) expressions: it must be possible to evaluate the expression at compile time. Function calls cannot: they must happen at runtime.

You could instead use a [static variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) within the `getIPWhitelist` function to have it only fetch from the database once:

```php
function getIPWhitelist()
{
  static $list = null;

  if(!$list) {
    // fetch from the database here (only executed once)
    $list = [
      '10.10.10.1',
      '10.10.10.2',
      '10.10.10.5',
    ];
  }

  return $list;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I;ve updated the question, not sure if it helps. Thanks